# Clear the main Panel to display the other reactive output in shiny r studio

Tags: r, shiny

I have a dataTableOutput in my main panel. Then I have an action button "Go". Once I click "Go" I want rHandsOutput to appear in the main panel but not beneath dataTableOutput. How can I remove dataTableOutput in the main panel and display rHandsOutput. In my current code both tables appearing together. Once I click "Go", the second table comes under the first table where I want to appear only second table (rHandsOutput) removing 1st table from the main panel.

Please help me!1

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `insertUI` and `removeUI` to make UI components dynamic. For example:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(


sidebarLayout(
  
  sidebarPanel(
    
    actionButton(inputId = "go", label = "Go")
    
  ),
  
mainPanel(
  
  fluidRow(
    tags$div(id = "firstOutput", 
           dataTableOutput("myDataTable"))
    ),
  
  fluidRow(
    tags$div(id = "placeholder") # the dynamic UI will be inserted relative to this placeholder
    )
))

)


server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$myDataTable <- renderDataTable(iris)
    
  observeEvent(input$go, {
    
    removeUI("div:has(>#firstOutput)")
    
    insertUI(
      selector = "#placeholder",
      where = "afterEnd", # inserts UI after the end of the placeholder element
      ui = fluidRow(
        actionButton(inputId = "newButton", label = "A new button")))
    
    })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `showElement()` and `hideElement()` from `shinyjs`:

```r
observeEvent(input$go, {
  shinyjs::hideElement(“firsttable”)
  shinyjs::showElement(“rHandsOutput”)
})
```

Assuming the ID of the first table is “firsttable” and the ID of the second table is “rHandsOutput”, and the ID of the “Go” button is “go”.

Answer (score -1):

Generate the ui dynamically.

Use `uiOutput("someidentifier")` in the `ui.r` and then fill it with your datatable with the following in `server.r`

```
output$someidentifier <- 
  renderUI({
    dataTableOutput("datatableidentifier")
  })

output$datatableidentifier <- renderDataTable(iris)
```

`uiOutput` takes the place (in `ui.r`) of whatever ui element you want to add dynamically. The necessary code for that ui then moves to `renderUI` in `server.r`.

Comment: This is just an alternative way of displaying the table in the ui and does not solve the problem posed.